# Using a jQuery effect to change the contents of a div?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am having a form and I would like to change it's contents based on the selected value of a drop down list. All the following will be used in a PHP file.

**It looks like this:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide {
 display:none;
}

<select>
<option value="" >Please select product below</option>
<option value="pro1">Product 1</option>
<option value="pro2">Product 2</option>
</select>

<div id="pro1" class="hide" >Product 1</div>
<div id="pro2" class="hide" >Product 2</div>
```

**A suggested solution is the following**

You can use the slideUp() and slideDown built-in effect.

Or any of the other built-in effects for jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
       $("#selectMenu").bind("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "pro1") {
            $("#pro1").slideDown();
            $("#pro2").slideUp();
        }
        else if($(this).val() =="pro2") {
            $("#pro2").slideDown();
            $("#pro1").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectMenu"> 
    <option value="" >Please select product below</option> 
    <option value="pro1">Product 1</option> 
    <option value="pro2">Product 2</option> 
</select>
```

**My questions are** How can I add the slideup/down script AND is there any other way to handle this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you visited this page? http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/ this explain everything you need about effects... as well as this page http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods

Comment: how about using a simple javascript like this example?
`<select onChange="javascript:document.getElementById('msg').value=this.value">
  <option value="Select one option">Select</option>
  <option value="OH YEA">YES</option>
  <option value="OH NO">NO</option>
</select>

<input id="msg" name="msg" type=text size=20>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My questions are How can I add the
>   slideup/down script AND is there any
>   other way to handle this?

If you make a convention that your `<option/>` value is the same as the id of the div you want to show, then you could alter your change event to look like this:

```
$("#selectMenu").bind("change", function() {
    $(".hide").slideUp().filter("#" + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/XcjpV/).